# SQL convert a correlated subquery to a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below **T-SQL** query uses a correlated subquery on SubmittedBy.PartyId in the where clause of the subquery.

This code is inside a stored procedure, where @SpecificBusinessGroup and @SpecificBusinessCategory are variables passed to the stored procedure. If the variables are passed in as null the query takes a few seconds to run. If the variables contain data, this query takes over an hour to run. That's why I am certain that the issue is pinpointed to this correlated subquery. I need help converting this to a JOIN'd derived table, but am having a hard time.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks much.

```
SELECT *

FROM 
    PremiumFinanceLoan pfl
    LEFT JOIN CustomerAccount c ON pfl.CustomerAccountId = c.PartyId 
    LEFT JOIN Entity SubmittedBy ON c.SubmittedById = SubmittedBy.PartyId
    LEFT JOIN ...

WHERE
    (@SpecificBusinessGroup IS NULL OR @SpecificBusinessCategory IS NULL OR EXISTS         
    (          
        select null    -- That way we will get one row for each group          
        from EntityBusinessCategoryMap as EBC         
            join BusinessCategory as BC on BC.BusinessCategoryId = EBC.BusinessCategoryId           
            join BusinessGroup as BG on BG.BusinessGroupId = BC.BusinessGroupId         
        where    
        (@SpecificBusinessGroup IS NULL OR          
            ( EBC.EntityId = SubmittedBy.PartyId AND BG.BusinessGroupId = @SpecificBusinessGroup))           
        AND (@SpecificBusinessCategory IS NULL OR          
            ( EBC.EntityId = SubmittedBy.PartyId AND BC.BusinessCategoryId = @SpecificBusinessCategory))             
    ))
```

Below is my solution, but I don't think it's correct in terms of, I don't think it's equivalent to the correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *

FROM 
    PremiumFinanceLoan pfl
    LEFT JOIN CustomerAccount c ON pfl.CustomerAccountId = c.PartyId 
    LEFT JOIN Entity SubmittedBy ON c.SubmittedById = SubmittedBy.PartyId

    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        select ebc.EntityId
        from EntityBusinessCategoryMap ebc
            join BusinessCategory bc on bc.BusinessCategoryId = ebc.BusinessCategoryId
            join BusinessGroup bg on bg.BusinessGroupId = bc.BusinessGroupId
        where
            (@SpecificBusinessGroup is null or bg.BusinessGroupId = @SpecificBusinessGroup)
            and (@SpecificBusinessCategory is null or bc.BusinessCategoryId = @SpecificBusinessCategory)
        group by ebc.EntityId
    ) gr on gr.EntityId = SubmittedBy.PartyId

    LEFT JOIN ...   

WHERE
    AND gr.EntityId IS NOT NULL -- Equivalent to EXISTS from the correlated subquery ???
```

Comment: i removed the mysql tag as this is sql-server

Comment: Can be `@SpecificBusinessGroup` and  `@SpecificBusinessCategory` both NULL or only one of them?

Comment: mcNets, yes both can be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `UNION` using two queries, then you don't need to use `GROUP BY`

```
LEFT JOIN 
(
    select ebc.EntityId 
    from EntityBusinessCategoryMap ebc
        left join BusinessCategory bc on bc.BusinessCategoryId = ebc.BusinessCategoryId
    where
        (@SpecificBusinessCategory is null or bc.BusinessCategoryId = @SpecificBusinessCategory)
    UNION
    select ebc.EntityId 
    from EntityBusinessCategoryMap ebc
        left join BusinessGroup bg on bg.BusinessGroupId = ebc.BusinessGroupId
    where
        (@SpecificBusinessGroup is null or bg.BusinessGroupId = @SpecificBusinessGroup)
) gr on gr.EntityId = SubmittedBy.PartyId
```

Comment: This does not work, it complains about ebc.BusinessGroupId does not exist in the EntityBusinessCategoryMap table. This table has only 3 columns -- a primary key, EntityId and BusinessCategoryId.

Answer (score 0):

This:

> If the variables are passed in as null the query takes a few seconds
>   to run. If the variables contain data, this query takes over an hour
>   to run.

means that you are running into the [parameter sniffing](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sql%20server%20parameter%20sniffing) issue. There are several ways to circumvent it, depending on your version of SQL Server:

1. The oldest is to create proxy variables for stored procedure parameters, and use them in the query. As crazy as it sounds, it's actually works.
2. You can specify the `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` query hint, so that SQL Server will build more averaged execution plan. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature/) is a short description of it.
3. The option of the last resort would be to specify `WITH RECOMPILE` in the stored procedure definition (or `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` in the query), but I don't recommend it - this thing should not be used unless all caveats are understood, since constant recompilations can put a significant strain on your system.

Comment: Thanks Roger. I have come across parameter sniffing in the past, and now make sure all of my stored procedures take it into account. Having said that, this specific stored procedure uses the proxy variables solution. In other words, we pass the variables to the sproc, and they are usually called @pABC. Then right below, we declare brand new variables by a slightly different name, and then assign pABC to it.

Comment: My gut feeling tells me that the issue here is with a correlated subquery. They are notoriously poor performing. That's why I am trying to convert it into a JOIN.

Comment: @Pavel, I see. Have you tried `optimize for unknown`? It can still help, actually.

Comment: Yes, I agree that correlation usually runs somewhat slower than join, but it's not the problem here. The problem is that MS SQL Server doesn't like `OR`-ed search predicates. I see two options here: rewrite the query, replacing `OR` with `UNION (all)`, if possible, or construct and execute the query dynamically, so only relevant filters would be included.

Comment: Thanks Roger, my solution above seems to have worked. Literally runs 57 minutes faster on a huge production database. We are talking seconds vs. minutes. All I did was replace the EXISTS with "SubmittedBy.PartyId IN", and removed the SubmittedBy.PartyId from the subquery. This effectively removes the correlation. It seems to have been the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Pretty much changed the **EXISTS** to an **IN**. By using EXISTS, this forces the subquery to be correlated since you use the SubmittedBy.PartyId inside the subquery to reference a table that is outside the subquery. By using IN, you make this into non-correlated subquery. The performance is good now.

```
SELECT *

FROM 
    PremiumFinanceLoan pfl
    LEFT JOIN CustomerAccount c ON pfl.CustomerAccountId = c.PartyId 
    LEFT JOIN Entity SubmittedBy ON c.SubmittedById = SubmittedBy.PartyId
    LEFT JOIN ...

WHERE
    (@SpecificBusinessGroup IS NULL OR @SpecificBusinessCategory IS NULL OR SubmittedBy.PartyId IN         
    (          
        select DISTINCT EBC.EntityId    -- That way we will get one row for each group          
        from EntityBusinessCategoryMap as EBC         
        inner join BusinessCategory as BC on BC.BusinessCategoryId = EBC.BusinessCategoryId           
        inner join BusinessGroup as BG on BG.BusinessGroupId = BC.BusinessGroupId         
        where    
        (@SpecificBusinessGroup IS NULL OR BG.BusinessGroupId = @SpecificBusinessGroup)          
        AND (@SpecificBusinessCategory IS NULL OR BC.BusinessCategoryId = @SpecificBusinessCategory)           
    ))
```